# how to make this jquery multiple toggle

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

```
$(".read-more-toggle").on("click", function () {
    $('.read-more-content').slideToggle( "slow" );
    $(".read-more-toggle").toggleClass("active");
});
```

right now if I have 2 toggles using the same css class both will open the same time.

How do I make it usable for multiple toggles.
Thank you in advance.

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#">TItle A</a></li>
<li><a href="#">TItle B</a></li>

<li class="read-more-toggle">TItle Above  <!-- CLOSING LI at bottom -->
<ul class="read-more-content hide">
   <li class="openhead">subtitle</li>
   <li><a href="https://#a">a</a></li>
   <li><a href="https://#b">b</a></li>
   <li class="openhead">subtitle</li>
   <li><a href="https://#c">c</a></li>
   <li class="openhead">subtitle</li>
   <li><a href="https://#d">d</a></li>
</ul><!-- END UL/read-more-content -->
</li><!-- END CLOSING main LI-->

<li><a href="#">TItle C</a></li>

<li class="read-more-toggle">Title Bottom<!-- li closing at bottom -->
<ul class="read-more-content hide">
   <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
   <li>body2</li>
   <li>body3</li>
</ul>
</li><!-- end Title Bottom -->

</ul>
```

it's CSS `.hide{display:none;}`

Comment: Can you please provide your HTML code

Comment: You can use `$(this)` or similar in the handler to identify the toggle that's been clicked, and then use that to find the content by navigating your DOM.

Comment: tschaefermedia - I have updated the html code needed. Rup- I have little to none knowledge of jquery. Original fiddle is here https://jsfiddle.net/ndgnsx60/4/